# socket timeout exception on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, solr, socket

We have solr router and shards. This appears in the jetty log of the router when doing faceted search across all the shards.

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry 
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry 
INFO: Retrying request
```

followed by exception about Internal Server Error. We run eighty shards distributed across several servers. Router runs on its own node.

UPD:
In the HttpCommComponent class of SOLR which sumbits requests to shards using HttpClient class I have noticed the following set on the MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager:
    mgr.getParams().setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(20);

it seems to me like too little setting for 80+ shards.

Comment: What are in the solr logs?

Comment: @tristan http://pastebin.com/FTVH1WF3 that is solr router log

Comment: @tristan http://pastebin.com/exwCx3LX that is the shard log, which port is mentioned in the solr router log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging I have found out, that one of the requests had a size of 4,4MB. The default maxPostSize in tomcat6 is 2MB (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html).

Changing that to 10MB has greatly improved situation on the solr side.

Answer (score 1):

The message is saying that your sever received a tcp-reset and therefore cannot continue.

I assume he was acting as a HTTP client? Is the target URL correct (ie not a closed port).

Using tcpdump or similar you should be able to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: do you suggest running tcpdump on the node with the router or on the shards?

Comment: ok. So ran tcpdump on the shards servers and listened to the router node. I get occasionally these: shard_node.9199 > router_node.45503: Flags [P.], cksum 0xab1a (incorrect -> 0x3561), seq 2896:4239, ack 1, win 634, options [nop,nop,TS val 431980810 ecr 924213364], length 1343      What does this tell?

Comment: ok. tcpdump does not show anything anomalous. Belief is that it is application (solr) level issue.

Comment: Well you should see an [R] packet no? Who's sending it when?

Comment: yes, many packet details were visible, including their hex and decoded representation. Nothing suspicious on that level. But as said, the POST packet size is limited by tomcat => see the answer. Thanks for helping!